# Delete all Rows after first occurrence of value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report with Data in columns A-L.

The number or rows in the report is dynamic.

I need to delete every row after the first instance of 0000004473 in column I.

I saw code for a similar question. In my spreadsheet the macro does the opposite and delete every row before 0000004473.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        'find Terminations
        Set rng = .Range("I:I").Find(what:="0000004473", after:=.Range("I1"))

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Get the start row
            sRow = rng.Row + 1

            'find last row
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                lastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", _
                    after:=.Range("I1"), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
            Else
                lastRow = 1
            End If
            'I use lastRow + 1 to prevent deletion "0000004773" when it is on lastrow
            .Range(sRow & ":" & lastRow + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: is `0000004473` actually text or is it a number that is formatted to show the preceeding `0`?

Comment: Its default is in general format so the zeros always show. If I convert to number it changes to 4473.

Comment: try searching for `4473`:  Set rng = .Range("I:I").Find(what:=4473, after:=.Range("I1"))`

Comment: Just tried not noticing any difference just seems to select all the values not delete them

Comment: Try `.Range(sRow & ":1040000").Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: Getting application-defined or object-defined error on that line when I tried

Comment: Just realized something after running the original code above the macro is deleting every row before 0000004473. so the opposite of what I need

Comment: Try intersecting with Worksheet.UsedRange

Comment: Sorry Joe still a newbie here not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.find` to get the last row. If you have data before `.range("I1")` it will use that as your `lastrow` value because it stops once it gets a match.

If you put `Debug.Print lastRow, sRow` where I have it below you can see what the range will be.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sRow As Long, lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        'find Terminations
        Set rng = .Range("I:I").Find(what:="0000004473", after:=.Range("I1"))

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Get the start row
            sRow = rng.Row + 1

            'find last row
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            Else
                lastRow = 1
            End If
            Debug.Print lastRow, sRow
            'I use lastRow + 1 to prevent deletion "0000004773" when it is on lastrow
            .Range(sRow & ":" & lastRow + 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Assuming "I" is the column with the most values, if it isn't use whatever column does.

Comment: Thank you this working great!!! Can I ask for one more thing? I now realize I need to delete all rows including the first instance of 0000004473 not just after. so there are 0 rows of 00000044773 in the report. would you be able to help with that?

Comment: Remove the ```+1``` from ```sRow = rng.Row + 1```